# Chaining transitions using the transition.end() promise

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, data-visualization, es6-promise

I'm trying to chain transitions by calling my `update` function when the `transition.end()` promise resolves. The following snippet lies within this `update` function. The full example, of which this snippet is a part, can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/fmgreenberg/1npLeguh/10/.

```js
let t = d3
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .end()
    .then(() => update(newData));
```

The issue is that the transition happens almost instantaneously, then the visualization sits there for ~3 seconds until update is called again. Why is this? If I comment out the last two lines of the snippet, the transition takes the expected 3 seconds. (Of course, there's just a single transition in this case since I've removed the loop.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of naming a transition instance, use the promise in the transition selection itself:

```
d3.select("#figure")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(newData, d => d)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("cx", (_, i) =>
      i < N ? (i + 1) * (2 * r + s) : 300 - (i - N + 1) * (2 * r + s)
    )
    .end()
    .then(() => update(newData));
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9gf8ybL/

And the corresponding S.O. snippet:

```js
let N = 5;
let r = 5;
let s = 2;

let data = d3.range(2 * N);

d3.select("#figure")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (_, i) =>
    i < N ? (i + 1) * (2 * r + s) : 300 - (i - N + 1) * (2 * r + s)
  )
  .attr("cy", 26)
  .attr("r", r)
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("fill", d => (d < N ? "white" : "black"));

update(data);

function update(data) {
  let I = data.slice(0, N);
  let J = data.slice(N, 2 * N);
  let i = randInt(N);
  let x = I[i];
  let j = randInt(N);
  let y = J[j];
  let newData = [
    ...I.slice(0, i),
    ...I.slice(i + 1),
    y,
    ...J.slice(0, j),
    ...J.slice(j + 1),
    x
  ];

  d3.select("#figure")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(newData, d => d)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("cx", (_, i) =>
      i < N ? (i + 1) * (2 * r + s) : 300 - (i - N + 1) * (2 * r + s)
    )
    .end()
    .then(() => update(newData));
}

function randInt(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="figure" viewBox="0 0 300 50" style="background-color: papayawhip; border-radius: 1rem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

However, if for any reason you still want to use a named transition instance, just use the more common `on("end"...)` method instead of the `end()` promise:

```
let t = d3
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .on("end", () => {
      update(newData)
    });
```

And then:

```
selection.transition(t)
    //etc...
```

Here is the JSFiddle with that approach: https://jsfiddle.net/8od3vkc1/

Comment: According to https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on, `transition.on("end", callback)` will fire the `callback` once for each element in the selection. I wanted it to fire once at the end of the whole transition, i.e, once for the whole selection, hence my use of the `end()` promise. In your second solution, does the callback only fire once because you defined it on the transition itself and not on the selection?

Comment: Yes, it fires only once, but you are correct: it fires only once in that specific scenario, if you used it in the transition selection, like the first snippet in my answer, it would fire for each element.